# Query that discards duplicate keys with parse.com SDK?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm researching how to implement leaderboards for my game with the parse.com SDK, my plan is to submit a score for the user every time they finish a level, attached to a "parent" leaderboard. I need to submit all scores because I need to retrieve leaderboards within time ranges (eg "all time", "last week", "last month", etc). The problem is, there'll be multiple scores for each user on the same leaderboard, and I only need to highest one. Is there a way to drop duplicate keys from a query? Is this the correct strategy? Everything else (sorting, paging, etc) seems to be in place.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a table with 'User_id', 'Score', 'Level', and 'Date' (or whatever you need). Each time that a player finishes a level, you put the score into the table.
Then you have to calculate each (all time, last week, etc) in the query.

E.g.
10 Highs of the day:

```
    SELECT TOP 10 User_id, Score, Date FROM Scores 
    WHERE Date = getdate()
    ORDER BY Score DESC
```

I don't know if I understood the question. Let me know if I didn't.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually the question was referring to the "parse.com" SDK for mobile apps. Thanks for the answer tho :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your question you want to retrieve data from Parse class. At the same time you want to eliminate the duplicate entry because user has multiple scores in different days. So to get the highest one, you have to query the class via query (based on SDK Android,iOS) and order by descending(based on your criteria), then obtain the first item in the result.

Or you can get the user all scores and create a structure where you can store the user scores as array list day by day. Based on day you can get the latest max or min scores. I hope I understand your question.

Hope this helps.Regards

Comment: Not exactly. I need to retrieve all the scores attached to a parent leaderboard, sorted by score, within a certain time period (weekly, monthly, etc). In that result I'll have duplicate scores for users as you mention. So I need to discard those, and get a result of multiple scores for different users, sorted by score.